# "Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'.System.Exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API with SQL Server using Entity Framework for the data layer. And while I tried to fetch data from database, my request stops at dataContext returning following exception. I have verified that the `UserRoles` table is created in database. Database setup is local.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'.

Comment: Does the table exists? Does user have access to it? Is the connection to correct database & schema?

Comment: @JamesZ  I am sure that table exists. I tried running sql generated from Linq in Sql Server Management Studio and it was executed successfully.I think there exists issues with connection to correct database but i have no idea to debug, please can you suggest way to verify connection?

Answer (score 0):

Open your edmx file in a text editor. If you see the tables in the file but not in the designer, try clearing out all the EntitySet nodes and EntityType nodes, save the file, then go back to Visual Studio and try the Update Model from Database again. Or before you do anything go to your Model and try right click on it -> Update model from database. Because probably your table is created on SQL but she does not exist yet in your model.

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="myModel.Store">
        <EntityContainer Name="MyModelStoreContainer">
            delete-> <EntitySet Name="Table1" ... />
            delete-> <EntitySet Name="Table2" ... />
        </EntityContainer>
            delete-> <EntityType Name="Table1">...</EntityType>
            delete-> <EntityType Name="Table2">...</EntityType>
  </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
```

Comment: Thank for the response. But I am using Database first approach and i have no edmx file.